# Performance issue with constructed classes, C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I am aware that this is an easy problem but I don't know how to do properly what I have in mind. I am using SFML but you don't need to understand how it works.
Here is my simple code snippet that generate tiles and assign them to a 2D-vector of tiles:
http://www.pastie.org/2665489

During the construction of the `TilePlane` object, each operation `(tilesMap[i]).push_back(tile)` takes far too long and I feel that I am copying data instead of using a more elegant method. So in this case, what is the good method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of performance issues in your code. If the bottleneck indeed comes from `push_back`, you should take Masoud's suggestion and push pointers onto the array and not values.

Another suggestion is that you declare your functions and constructors to use references - for example:

```
Tile::Tile(const Tileset& tileset, int tileId, int posX, int posY)
```

instead of

```
Tile::Tile(Tileset tileset, int tileId, int posX, int posY)
```

Passing the parameter by value will force a copy to be created, which can be expensive. Passing by const reference guarantees the object is not copied or modified.

Comment: thanks it's solved. The problem was indeed coming from me not passing a reference to the tileset, so the whole tileset was copied each time.
I am used to Java where no object is copied

Answer (score 1):

As you said maybe the problem is `(tilesMap[i]).push_back(tile)`,
when you insert an object of `tile` to the list, in fact you are copying an `sf::Image` entirely(Beacause of `copy-constructor` of `sf::Image`).

You should put pointers of `tile`s to the list. Something like below:

```
...
      Tile *tile_ptr = new Tile(tileset, rand() % tileset.getSize(), i*32, j*32);

      (tilesMap[i]).push_back(tile_ptr);
...
```

**Dont forget**, you must `delete` `tile_ptr` objects in right time. For example in `~TilePlane()`, you must iterate the list and `delete` the tile objects.